# How can I assign a color to a specific value in a column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, colors, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns: state, total, politics. I am trying to use sns.barplot to show a simple plot of each state with the total and color the state based on the value in the 'politics' column. 
To illustrate, here's the bar chart I want done with Tableau:
[Tableau bar chart - good!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuBAQ.png)

However, when I plot in seaborn, I can't seem to figure out how to assign the states with "Red" as their value in the politics column to the actual color red on the graph!
The color palette seems to randomly assign colors to values, so "Red" states have blue bars, "Blue" states have green bars and "Swing" states have orange bars... it's confusing to the reader!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to assign the proper colors values using the `palette` argument of `.barplot`. But you also have to tell seaborn what color is each word in `politics` column assigned to, you can do this with one more column:

```
>>> data
   total     state politics
0  16.99     Maine      Red
1  10.34    Oregon     Blue
2  21.01  Colorado    Swing
3  23.68      Utah    Swing
4  24.59  Arkansas      Red
5  25.29      Iowa     Blue
```

Now we define a dictionary with the color mapping and use `.apply` with a `lambda` function to create a new column:

```
>>> colors = {'Red':'red','Blue':'blue','Swing':'yellow'}
>>> data['color'] = data['politics'].apply(lambda x: colors[x])
>>> data
   total     state politics   color
0  16.99     Maine      Red     red
1  10.34    Oregon     Blue    blue
2  21.01  Colorado    Swing  yellow
3  23.68      Utah    Swing  yellow
4  24.59  Arkansas      Red     red
5  25.29      Iowa     Blue    blue
```

Notice it was also necessary to make "Red" and "Blue" lowercase, since `matplotlib` won't recognise those colors capitalised. Now we just need to use `.barplot` as usual, using the `palette` argument:

```
>>> sns.barplot(x='total',y='state',palette=data['color'], data=data)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I got this working and it looks great :) - my only add here would be that I got key errors because I had some states in the dataset with NaN in the other columns. I wasn't sure how to handle that, but I realized they needed come out anyhow.

Comment: I'm glad to help, since it answered your question you should [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it!

Comment: Done!! Appreciate the help (I'm pretty new to this :)